# What languages to write windows shell extensions

Tags: windows, com, windows-shell

I know how to write shell extesions in python.
The drawbacks are

- it does not work on 64 bit Windows
- I am unsure how creating a python process everytime something “happens” reduces performance.

I know how to write shell extensions using .Net (C#)
The drawbacks are

- [discouraged by MS](http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2006/12/18/1317290.aspx)
- I am unsure how this reduces performance. (does it?)

I have seen shell extenions written in (free)pascal.

- Are there drawbacks using this approach
- Does this work with 64bit windows.

Obviosly one can write shell extensions using c or c++

- Well... I am still trying to understand com in c and c++....

What other optios are there, what other languages ?
Do they have drawbacks?

Comment: There's no "C/C++" language. COM is extremely painful in C, but quite doable in C++.

Comment: MSalters: I think you referred to my using "c/c++" as kind of one language - so I corrected that.

Comment: COM programming is a bit more explicit, but far more versatile in C actually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since .NET 4 came along, MS now do support .Net for Shell Extensions, since the major problem (cannot host multiple CLR versions in shell) has been solved through the [side-by-side](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee819091.aspx) mechanism:

> With the ability to have multiple
>   runtimes in process with any other
>   runtime, we can now offer general
>   support for writing managed shell
>   extensions—even those that run
>   in-process with arbitrary applications
>   on the machine. We still do not
>   support writing shell extensions using
>   any version earlier than .NET
>   Framework 4 because those versions of
>   the runtime do not load in-process
>   with one another and will cause
>   failures in many cases.

Comment: ok, nice... Doesn't make it faster, though? Or is the lack of performanc just my imagination?

Comment: I wouldn't expect performance issues to arise - and your presumption of a new CLR process being spun up for every action would seem to be incorrect.

Comment: This isn't entirely true, at least with regards to the emphasis on supporting pre-.NET 4 extensions. If a .NET 2 shell extension loads into Explorer first, the .NET 4 extensions cannot be. This only works if the first extension loaded is .NET 4 and that's hard (if not impossible) to guarantee. As there are .NET 2 extensions out there (even though not officially supported) there are chances that a .NET 4 one won't load on someone's machine. Frustrating, but true. Still +1.

Answer (score 0):

because explorer is running all the time, please use a language that is efficient and close to the OS as possible. C or C++ please.

Comment: isn't pascal (or vb6, which I forgot above) equally fast when compiled?

Comment: vb6 definitely not. i don't know anything about pascal. but i'm more interested in relaying the concept than the specific language to use.

Comment: I'm surprised i'd get voted down for supporting the same advice as the blog link in the OP