# Using windows explorer for other file storage via .net

Tags: c#, windows-explorer

I've seen software products that interface with windows explorer for sharing cloud drives, one was for using gmail as a drive. Is there any documentation on what libraries etcetera are used to accomplish this task?

1. I'm not looking to use Gmail (specifically)
2. I'm more concerned about
   how to access the windows-explorer interface for showing items that
   are not on a real disk.

Comment: looks like everything boils down to windows shell extensions which don't look friendly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to create a Windows shell extension.

[This article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188741.aspx) looks promising - although quite old.

However, as stated in that article, you are discouraged to build a shell extension with managed code.

Comment: seems like the 'managed code' issue has been resolved? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3509840/what-languages-to-write-windows-shell-extensions

Comment: also see: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/codefx/archive/2010/09/14/writing-windows-shell-extension-with-net-framework-4-c-vb-net-part-1.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You should download open-source software such as [gDisk](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gdisk/files/gdisk/gDisk-0.6/gDisk-0.6-sources.zip/download) to see how they are doing it. Or you can see how it is done in Firefox using [Gspace](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/gspace/). Here are some general guidelines for developing such applications:

1. You need some way to distinguish files from email (labels, subject line, etc).
2. You need an interface to login to the GMail website and cache those credentials.
3. You need an interface to send an email to yourself.
4. Finally, you need a way to access those "files".

Comment: It's the same for Mac apps.  He might have linked a windows app, but the question was for documentation on how to do it.  IMO, this is a good answer.  +1

Comment: please note that the question is tagged c# AND the subject line states '.net'

Comment: @Chris: That is immaterial because it has nothing to do with .NET

Comment: @0A0D I think I know what the question is about because I asked it

Comment: @Chris: Again, it has nothing to do with .NET. The language is immaterial in this case.